# Cannot register default instance MSSQLSERVER in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Developer on Windows 7 (64 bit). In SQL Management Studio I cannot register the default instance MSSQLSERVER. It cannot find it although the service is running. I get the message:

> Cannot connect to PHOENIX\MSSQLSERVER.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)

However SQL Server Management Studio does show the SQL Server 2005 Express instance (that was installed with VS 2008 Pro) which appeared as already registered. I am using Windows Authentication as I installed it in mixed mode.

How do I connect to an MSSQLSERVER instance using SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 28):

I always connected as:

`[machine_name]/[instance_name]`

and it wasn't able to connect. What works is connecting simply as:

`[machine_name]`

This is probably due to the fact that I am running a DEFAULT instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the server allows remote connections on TCP/IP port 1433.

this can be checked by SQL Server 2008 configuration manager.

Go to network configuration and check if tcp/ip is enabled. If not enable this one.