# SQL Server 2008 service not running

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, windows-7

I updated my Windows 7 to SP1 for the purpose to install Visual Studio 2013. I am successfully done my job to install Visual Studio 2013. But the problem arises when I try to install SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2 Management Studio.

The SQL Server service is not running in `services.msc` and the SQL Server Browser service is not even listed in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Please help me because I have install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio several times and update it also to SQL Server SP1 but still not running SQL Server service in `services.msc`.

Due to this I cannot connect my database engine.

Providing I also enter the correct instance name several times by following the link
[Cannot register default instance MSSQLSERVER in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960176/cannot-register-default-instance-mssqlserver-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Well, if you install **only** the **Management Studio**- then you **only** have the GUI admin tool - but ***NOT*** the actual database engine! You need to install **both** the actual SQL Server 2008 database engine (or preferably a more recent one - 2008 and 2008 R2 are going out of mainstream support pretty soon) and *then* add Management Studio

Comment: Well this management studio worked for me before I update my windows 7 to SP1. The same management studio setup i use this time also.

Comment: Yes, but the Management Studio is no **server** - there is no **database engine** in the Management Studio install. But most likely, installing VS 2013, you've also installed the SQL Server Express (possibly LocalDB) version. However, if you don't see any "SQL Server" service in the SQL Server Configuration Manager console --> then you just don't have an engine to connect to - you'll need to install one

Comment: Ok Thanks I will download the SQL SERVER 2008 Express then after that i will tell you.

Comment: As I said - if I were you, I'd try to get a **more recent** version - SQL Server 2012 or 2014 Express ...